# How do I use browser.findElements() to count and iterate through elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, protractor

I'm testing a web page with the following elements in it:

```html
<span class="step-count ng-binding">1</span>
<span class="step-count ng-binding">2</span>
<span class="step-count ng-binding">3</span>
<span class="step-count ng-binding">4</span>
```

First I want to count them so I've tried the following code:

```js
it('make sure all elements exist at page', function() {
    var x = browser.findElements(by.css('.step-count.ng-binding'));
    expect(x.length).toEqual(4);
});
```

and

```js
it('make sure all elements exist at page', function() {
    var x = browser.findElements(by.css('.step-count.ng-binding'));
    expect(x.size).toEqual(4);
});
```

Both produced a failure message:

> Failures: Expected undefined to equal 4.

How do I count them properly in my ProtractorJS project and how do I iterate over them afterwards in order to compare text or any other properties that might be added later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *overcomplicating the problem*. Using `$$()` and [`.count()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) and [`.getText()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText):

```
var elements = $$('.step-count');

expect(elements.count()).toEqual(4);
expect(elements.getText()).toEqual(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
```

---

Note how we don't need to resolve into the array of elements - both `count()` and `getText()` methods are available on the [`ElementArrayFinder`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) (the result of `element.all()` or `$$()`) and the `expect()` in Jasmine/Protractor knows what a promise is and would resolve it before making an expectation.

---

Also note that it is not a good idea to use `ng-binding` class in your locators - it is a pure technical Angular class that doesn't provide any valuable, unique, data-oriented and meaningful information. If you want to enforce not having Angular classes or other technical attributes used inside locators, you can use `ESLint` static code analysis tool and `eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin which has the [`no-angular-classes`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-angular-classes.md) and [`no-angular-attributes`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-angular-attributes.md) relevant rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.all()` to find all the elements with same locator in Protractor. Use the following code:

```
element.all(by.css('.step-count.ng-binding')).then(function(listOfElements){
    //verify the count of elements   
    expect(listOfElements.count()).toEqual(4);

    //iterate on list of elements
    listOfElements.each(function(eachElement){
        eachElement.getText().then(function(text){
           console.log("Ele Text:"+text);
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: `listOfElements.count()` wont work because it is an array. It should be something like `expect(listOfElements.length).toEqual(4);`

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj, thanks Man. I thought it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank @GillesC and @Suresh Salloju for the following code that worked for me:

```
it('make sure all elements exist at page', function() {
        var x = element.all(by.css('.step-count.ng-binding')).then(function (items) {
            expect(items.length).toBe(4);
        });
        for (let i = 1; i < x.length; ++i) {
            expect(x[i].getText()).toBe(i.toString());
        }
    });
```